# Внедрение js в браузер GetElementById

Tags: javascript, webbrowser

Всех приветствую.
Вышла проблемка с внедрением текста в input по средствам js.
Я использую `GetElementById("id_name").value = "extext";`

Но есть проблема. Сайт не воспринимает такой текст. Вставленный из буфера или введенный руками работает отлично. Но текст который внедряется с помощью js - он не видит(хотя в поле для ввода он появляется).
Вопрос в том, есть ли другие способы импортировать свой текст в строку через js, что-бы сайт его видел и воспринимал нормально. Что-то кроме value.
Всех заранее благодарю за любой ответ.

Comment: Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Что конкретно не так, и какого результата хотите добиться?

Comment: У меня проблема в том, что при использовании кода текст вставляется, но окно его не видит. То есть если я ввожу его руками - окно видит мой текст. Но при использовании value - текст появляется но сайт его не воспринимает

Comment: Текст точно импортируется куда надо, предоставьте тогда данные как Вы его вставляете, скорее всего там ошибка.

Comment: Нет. Вы не верно поняли.
Я использую document.getElementById('formElement_0').value='sdgsdgsd';
в окне авторизации. Но сайт после заполнения двух инпутов подобным образом - кнопка авторизации не активна.(что происходит, когда ввожу руками или вставляю из буфера)

Comment: Покажите код, который у Вас открывает кнопку авторизации - сделаем. Вам надо просто добавить проверку на наличие данных в поле.

Comment: Но сайт не мой. И проверка там уже есть.
Просто у сайта нету api, а мне нужно прописать авторизацию автоматическую(GET/POST не то что мне нужно)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104792/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-404).

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var z = document.getElementById('123');
    z.value = '123';// Так Вы добавляете текст в value (значение)
    z.innerText = "123" // Так добавляется текст в само поле.

    console.log(document.getElementById('123').value);
```

```html
<input id="123">
```

Comment: Это не то что мне нужно, но спасибо за ответ. innerText все так же не импортирует его в input сайта который мне нужен

Comment: @404 Добавил данные в консоль, чтобы было видно, что данные вставлены через js, и получены через него же.

Comment: Нет. Я понимаю что это должно так работать. Но мой сайт не воспринимает это таким образом. Окно попросту остается пустым :(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
let elem_info=document.getElementById('info') ;
elem_info.innerHTML='your text';
```

Где info соответственно id нужного элемента

Comment: Попробовал. Та же штука что и с комментарием выше. Очень специфический сайт. Окно попросту остается пустым, хоть консоль и не ругается

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо выяснить, на какое событие код страницы меняет состояние кнопки - `change`, `keypress`, `keyup`.

```js
function test() {
  var input = document.getElementById("testinput");
  input.value = "test me";
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}

function activate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("testinput");
  var button = document.getElementById("testbutton");
  button.disabled = input.value == "";
}
```

```html
<input id="testinput" onchange="activate()" />
<button disabled id="testbutton">Activate</button>
<br/><br/>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
```